# Php check for file_get_contents in loop

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, file-get-contents

How can I check if there is content using `file_get_contents` and printing the content out if there is one.

I tried following but it did not work:
( I am using laravel blade syntax )

```
    @if(file_get_contents($images[$i]->scenes) == 0) //empty
        <img class="input-preview" src="{{ asset('img/placeholder654x363.png') }}">
    @else
        <img class="input-preview" src="{{ 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($images[$i]->scenes)) }}">
```

I get the error because I have two files(string paths) like this:

> 0 -> no image 1 -> image

That why I am trying to loop through and getting the content if there is content.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [file_exisits()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: This question kind of lacks a further explanation, are you sure there's even anything in the $images array?
Can you elaborate..?

Comment: the array holds 2 values the frist one is empty and the second is not (hold the image path)

Comment: @bub ok it worked with file exists

Comment: @bub do you want to post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you using `file_get_contens` result return is a string, then if this file empty you will get empty string

So use this code

```
@if(!file_exists($images[$i]->scenes) || file_get_contents($images[$i]->scenes) == false) //empty
    <img class="input-preview" src="{{ asset('img/placeholder654x363.png') }}">
@else
    <img class="input-preview" src="{{ 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($images[$i]->scenes)) }}">
```

- `!file_exists($images[$i]->scenes)` mean file not exist
- `file_get_contents($images[$i]->scenes) == false` file exist and have empty content

These are different.

Comment: @JohnDoe2 In this case file already exist and have empty content you will use `file_get_contents($images[$i]->scenes) == false`.

Comment: That comment was for you first answer, before your edit

Comment: @JohnDoe2 No problems bro. Hope this working for you.